# Why wordpress theme css and js files load after the head tag?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, linker-errors

Why my wordpress theme css and js files load after the head tag ? And showing the red color like the snapshot in view source at firefox which means wrong markup.

What's going wrong in my code ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting a question.

Comment: When I build a wordpress theme I faced this problem. I share my problem what I faced and how I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_head()` function (which is just a wrapper function dor `wp_head`) should be inside the `<head></head>` tags. `wp_enqueue_scripts` which is the hook used to add scripts and styles are hooked to the `wp_head` hook.

Remember, `<link>` tags outside the `<head></head>` tags are invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may wrongly insert the wp_head() function after the head tag like the following code

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<?php wp_head(); ?
```

The proper way is to do this like the following code

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<?php wp_head(); ?
</head>
```